# Decode Googles Base64

Tags: c#, google-api, base64

I was trying to decode a Base64 String from Googles Gmail API, 
the string is:
`PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBYSFRNTCAxLjAgVHJhbnNpdGlvbmFsLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSL3hodG1sMS9EVEQveGh0bWwxLXRyYW5zaXRpb25hbC5kdGQiPg0KPGh0bWwgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGh0bWwiPg0KPGhlYWQ-DQo8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJ-`

I used:
`Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);`

But I also Tryed Googles "Google.Protobuf" Package:
`ByteString.FromBase64(Base64String);`

Both throw the Error

> FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

The online Decoder https://www.base64decode.org/ has no problem Decoding 
The String is from Googles Gmail Api (`message.Payload.Body.Data`) 
And [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWok4K) is a quick online Project

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code why arnt you using part.Body.Data?

Comment: I think your Base64 is a [variant of Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table). Presumably the "RFC 4648" one in the table.

Comment: Yes it is RFC4648, how do I tell my Converter?

Comment: @John there are multiple RFC 4648 variants :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input looks like RFC 4648 §5 base-64, i.e. without padding and with `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/`. `Convert.FromBase64String` wants RFC 4648 §4 base-64 *with* padding. This works, for example:

```cs
string s = @"PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBYSFRNTCAxLjAgVHJhbnNpdGlvbmFsLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSL3hodG1sMS9EVEQveGh0bWwxLXRyYW5zaXRpb25hbC5kdGQiPg0KPGh0bWwgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGh0bWwiPg0KPGhlYWQ-DQo8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOCIgLz4NCjx0aXRsZT5WZXJpZmljYXRpb24gRW1haWw8L3RpdGxlPg0KPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0idmlld3BvcnQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9IndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCwgaW5pdGlhbC1zY2FsZT0xLjAiLz4NCjxzdHlsZT4NCnRkIHtwYWRkaW5nLXJpZ2h0OjE1cHg7DQpwYWRkaW5nLWxlZnQ6MTVweDt9DQp0aCB7cGFkZGluZy1yaWdodDoxNXB4Ow0KcGFkZGluZy1sZWZ0OjE1cHg7fQ0KcCB7cGFkZGluZzogNXB4O30NCjwvc3R5bGU-DQo8L2hlYWQ-DQo8Ym9keSBzdHlsZT0ibWFyZ2luOiAwOyBwYWRkaW5nOiAwOyI-DQogPHA-RmFzdCBnZXNjaGFmZnQsPC9wPg0KIDxwPm51ciBub2NoIGVpbmVuIFNjaHJpdHQg4oCTIGRlciBLbGljayBhdWYgZGVuIGZvbGdlbmRlbiBMaW5rIGJlc3TDpHRpZ3QgZGVpbmUgenVtIE5ld3NsZXR0ZXIuIEhlcnpsaWNoZW4gRGFuayE8L3A-DQogPHA-QW5tZWxkdW5nIGJlc3TDpHRpZ2VuIDwvcD4NCiA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwczovL3Rlc3QtYXBwLmJsdW1lMjAwMC5kZS9teS1tZW51L3Byb2ZpbGU_c3Vic2NyaWJlPVRydWUmc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uSWQ9MTAiPiBodHRwczovL3Rlc3QtYXBwLmJsdW1lMjAwMC5kZS9teS1tZW51L3Byb2ZpbGU_c3Vic2NyaWJlPVRydWUmc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uSWQ9MTA8L2E-DQo8YnI-DQo8cD5EZWluIEJMVU1FIDIwMDAtVGVhbTwvcD48L2JvZHk-DQo8L2h0bWw-";
s = s.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'); // change alphabet
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

If other inputs complain about padding discrepencies, you'll need to manually add padding, for example:

```cs
s = s.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/') + (s.Length % 4) switch {
    2 => "==",
    3 => "=",
     _ => "",
};
```